# Failed to parse Adb version -Wrong ELF Class

Tags: 11.10, installation, java, android, eclipse

My PC CONFIGURATION :
`UBUNTU 11.10 version 64 bit ,
ECLIPSE 3.7 ,
ANDROID SDK`
 I tried hard to remove adb error but itsms not working and showing following Errors:

```
/platform-tools/adb:Error While loading Shared libraries
```

`libncurses.so.5:wrong ELF class:ELFCLASS64`

I even set all path for android set correctly but it wont works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elf (executable and link format) problem is due to your setup using amd64 and i386 stuff. The official Android SDK only runs on i386 JVM, so you need to manually specify the i386 JVM on Eclipse.

1. First install the <strike>Sun</strike>(Oracle) 32-bit JVM. [Here is](http://brunoreis.com/tech/intalling-java-ubuntu-natty/) a step-by-step on how to do this:
2. Add the JVM to Eclipse. Navigate:

   ```
   Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Add
   ```

   Put the location of the JVM. Probably will be `/usr/lib/jvm/java7/` (my is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-sun-1.7.0.01`). The external libraries will be *automatically* added when you put the location of the JVM.
    [image: Java7 Add Eclipse]
3. Set the <strike>Sun</strike> (Oracle) 32-bit JVM as default.
    [image: Java7 Default Eclipse]

Comment: Link in first item is broken.  Leads to "Access denied" page.

Answer (score 0):

As Marcos said, it's related to 32bit compatibility on your system.

Another solution, quite less elegant i must admit, is to install the 32 bit compatibility on your system :

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```